# Advanced cascade delete

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, dapper

I have a very simple database whose schema is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tags
(
    TagName NVARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Posts
(
    PostSlug NVARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
    Title NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.PostTagJunction 
(
    PostSlug NVARCHAR(100),
    TagName  NVARCHAR(100)
    PRIMARY KEY (PostSlug, TagName),
    FOREIGN KEY (PostSlug) REFERENCES dbo.Posts (PostSlug)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (TagName)  REFERENCES dbo.Tags (TagName)
);
```

I want to make it so that when I delete a post from `dbo.Posts` that resulting non-referenced tags in `dbo.Tags` are also deleted.

Consider the following code:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Posts
    VALUES ('hello-world', 'Hello World');
INSERT INTO dbo.Tags
    VALUES ('Introduction');
INSERT INTO dbo.PostTagJunction
    VALUES ('hello-world', 'Introduction'); 
DELETE 
FROM dbo.Posts
WHERE postslug = 'hello-world'
```

Because I use the cascade delete option, the post is removed from `dbo.Posts` and the record is removed from `dbo.PostTagJunction`. However, despite being an orphan, the `hello-world` record in `dbo.Tags` remains. I want to delete the tag too. How?

I should emphasizes that if the tag is being used by another post, it should *not* be deleted. Thank you.

I am using `Dapper` and `C#` to communicate with the database.

Comment: No magic! 
1> use delete query for the tag, deleted from PostTagJunction.
2>use trigger as @Dn24Z said.

Comment: @MitchWheat How so...? Bare in mind this is a simple database. If I wasn't using the cascade action, I would just be executing two Delete statements from my code. I lack the experience to know which option is best so I would really appreciate an elaborated!

Comment: FWIW, I never use cascading delete but always write appropriate stored procedures to handle the work. It helps to avoid massive mistakes when an ad hoc deletion goes bad and it allows for other checks and balances, e.g. additional sanity checks and archiving. It also has a security benefit as you can grant users access to the stored procedure without allowing them to delete data directly from the tables, perhaps with additional checks, e.g. a manager can only delete their own employees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible to delete the parent table records by deleting child table records using cascading option. Create a new stored procedure to delete the `Posts, Tags, PostTagJunction` based on the *PostSlug* (`@PostSlug`) passing from C# application as parameter.

Drop the Cascading constraint in the `PostTagJunction` table and try something like this.

```
DECLARE @PostSlug NVARCHAR(100) = 'hello-world'
DECLARE @TagName NVARCHAR(100) = ''

SELECT @TagName= TagName FROM PostTagJunction WHERE PostSlug =@PostSlug
DELETE PostTagJunction WHERE PostSlug =@PostSlug

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PostTagJunction WHERE TagName =@TagName)
DELETE Tags WHERE TagName =@TagName

DELETE Posts WHERE PostSlug =@PostSlug
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Selva. I may do this but instead of creating a stored procedure, run the crux of your query, which is the third "phase" from my code.

Answer (score 3):

You can denormalize your database using a trigger, in other words you can create a `FOR DELETE` trigger on `dbo.Posts` which will automatically delete your record in an orphan `dbo.Tags` table, example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerName
    ON dbo.Posts
    FOR DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM dbo.Tags
    WHERE TagName IN (SELECT TagName FROM DELETED)
GO
```

Comment: Thank you, Dn247. Using a trigger crossed by mind but as a Sql newbie, I have heard they should be a last resort. I thought I would ask here for some input before using one. I _may_ still use one. I'm not sure yet.